# Assign image from picturebox to rdlc report

Tags: c#, rdlc, windows-forms-designer

i wanna know if its possible to Add a picture from an Picturebox inside my gui to an rdlc report. Right now im doing this for all the string, but i want to add a single picture as well.

reportViewer3.Visible = true;

```
        DataSet2 DsActivityReport = new DataSet2();
        ReportDataSource reportDataSource = new ReportDataSource();
        reportDataSource.Name = "DataSet1";
        reportDataSource.Value = DsActivityReport.Tables[0];


        ReportParameter name = new ReportParameter("NAME", txtNAME.Text);
        ReportParameter employee_id = new ReportParameter("EMPLOYEE_ID", txtEmpNo.Text);
        ReportParameter company_id = new ReportParameter("COMPANY_ID", txtCompany.Text);
        ReportParameter emp_no = new ReportParameter("EMP_NO", txtEmpNo.Text);
        //ReportParameter emp_picture = new ReportParameter("picture", );

        reportViewer3.LocalReport.EnableExternalImages = true;
        reportViewer3.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();

        reportViewer3.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { name, employee_id, company_id, emp_no});
        reportViewer3.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(reportDataSource);

        reportViewer3.RefreshReport();
```

i Really hope there is some help out there, since im pretty lost.. Have tried to do this all day, but can't find any solution to my problem.

i tried to do this:

value of my parameter called picture.
=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!picture.Value)

and the code:

```
 public string ConvertImgToBase64String()
    {
        byte[] arrpic;
        using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            picEmployee.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
            arrpic = ms.ToArray();
        }
        string base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(arrpic);
        return base64String;
    }
  ReportParameter Picture = new ReportParameter("picture", ConvertImgToBase64String());

reportViewer3.LocalReport.SetParameters(new ReportParameter[] { name, employee_id, company_id, emp_no, Picture });
```

but the image doesn't and there is no error message.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim arrPic as byte() = /*Load the image as array of byte
Convert byte() to BASE64 */
Dim sIMGBASE64 as String = Convert.ToBase64String(arrPic))
/*Add the BASE64 stream to the parameters*/
paramList1.Add(New ReportParameter(<sparamname>, sIMGBASE64)
```

On the Report set the "Value" property of Picture Box like this:

```
Value=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters!<sparamname>.Value)
```

**try this with your code.**

Comment: i edit my question with the new solution, but it still gives me problems.

Comment: in c# :
`byte[] arrPic = /*Load the image as array of byte*/
string sIMGBASE64 = Convert.ToBase64String(arrPic);
paramList1.Add(New ReportParameter("<sparamname>", sIMGBASE64);


Value=System.Convert.FromBase64String(Parameters["<sparamname>"].Value);`

Comment: still not working.. I tried updateing question, with the code i used, as youness and mansres described..